# Find exact match and return row number where found

Tags: excel-formula

in table `k1:s10` find exact match of `a1:g1` and return number of the row where it found to `h1`.

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQuq8.png)

EDIT based on Darren Bartrup-Cooks suggestion.
[image]

Comment: 7 Columns including K stops at Q not S, are there another 2 columns?  And if so, can the sequence be anywhere in those columns?  And are we talking same order or just all are there is some order?

Comment: There's probably a much better way to do it. :) `=(LEN(LEFT(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,K1:Q10),SEARCH(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:G1),TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,K1:Q10))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,K1:Q10),SEARCH(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:G1),TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,K1:Q10))-1),",","")))/7+1`

Comment: HI Darren and thank you it gives error name and i dont know where and why but look right path

Comment: Darren is awesome